# submit multiple forms by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit multiple forms thru ajax post, but the problem is the server returns an empty array in post.

Here are the codes in my JS:

```
$('#check_test').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var results = [];
    $('form').each(function(){
        results.push($(this).serialize());
    });

    $.ajax({
        'url': 'handler/test_handler.php',
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify(results),
        'dataType': 'html',
        'success': function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

In server side:

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST)); // null
var_dump($_POST); // empty array
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no `method` attribute, its `type`:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'handler/test_handler.php',
    'type': 'POST', // type not method
    'data': {data: JSON.stringify(results)},
    'dataType': 'html',
    'success': function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

`method` is the attribute used in your `<form>` tags.

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/izYisH)

Sidenote: I think `serializeArray()` is much more suitable:

```
results.push($(this).serializeArray());
```

[Another example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/b3O1uP)

Comment: `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>`

Comment: @excluded_once Instead of sending a serialized string, you should send key - value pairs if you want to access them with `$_POST`. For example: `'data': { 'my_data': JSON.stringify(results) },`

Comment: @excluded_once here is an example so you'll see http://codepad.viper-7.com/izYisH

Comment: @excluded_once sure, glad this shed some light